# How to downgrade auto renew subscription in Flutter IOS

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

I have used [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase)
There is a function for price change specially designed for ios please help where and how to use